# How to make a query builder that find Properties based on Request

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony4, query-builder

I have a estate web app in symfony4 and I have db sql structure : tables(Requests - any client can request to buy a property,  Properties - the actual buildings, Fields - the dynamic field type used to custom form, like ElectricCurrent, TV, AC and FieldValues - the relation between either a property or a request and a field, like property 3 got street lighting or like in request nr 4 the client requested properties with street lighting) 
Task: to make a query builder that return all properties matched based on a request.

---

First I joined (in PropertiesRepository) FieldValues for each property:

```
$qb->innerJoin(FieldValues::class,"fieldsValues", 'WITH', 'fieldsValues.property = p.id');
```

Then, for each FieldValue of the request, I tried to :

- 1.) check if the property have this kind of FieldValue, because when a client add his property, he can either add specific fieldsValues, either not

```
// $fieldValReq is the fieldValue of the request from the current iteration 
// fieldsValues.field represent FieldValue's Field Id
$qb
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq("fieldsValues.field", ':valueF'))
    ->setParameter('valueF', $fieldValReq->getField()->getId())
```

- 2.) check if the value of the FieldValue from properties found are the Request's FieldValue

```
$qb
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq("fieldsValues.value", ':valueV'))
   ->setParameter('valueV', $fieldValReq->getValue())
```

everything is happening inside the foreach that iterates through the request fieldValues

---

The problem is that, after the first iteration, example (the second iteration), the query builder results get down to 0 because THIS piece of code executed in the first iteration already matched by id of fieldValue (example street lighting) and now tries to match again the found results, by id of current fieldValue (example PVC Windows) and this can t be done cause of one id cannot match 2 different things .

```
$qb
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq("fieldsValues.field", ':valueF'))
    ->setParameter('valueF', $fieldValReq->getField()->getId())
```

---

My only solution was to get a different set of results for each fieldValue and to make a php function that make the intersection of all result sets, but this is a mess when database number of records get bigger . I need a query builder that find properties that match the exact request fields .

ALL PICTURES ARE FORM FIELDVALUES TABLE

- 1.) looking for fieldValues of request nr id 1022
  [image]
- 2.) looking for properties that match request nr id 1022 fieldValues
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic parameter names!

```
    $valueFName = sprintf('valueF%d', $fieldValReq->getField()->getId());
    $valueVName = sprintf('valueV%d', $fieldValReq->getField()->getId());
    $qb
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq("fieldsValues.field", ':'.$valueFName))
        ->setParameter($valueFName, $fieldValReq->getField()->getId());

    $qb
       ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq("fieldsValues.value", ':'.$valueVName))
       ->setParameter($valueVName, $fieldValReq->getValue());
```

Comment: It's obvious that you need dynamic parameter names when you set them in a loop. Otherwise you would bind just the last value to the same parameter. If it still not working, then there are more issues which I cannot see. You should provide more code and sql schemata.